# Getting multiple phone numbers from selected contact

Tags: android

I am developing an application in which i am using startactivity result and accessing default android phonebook in my application, after that on selecting one contact i am getting name, one phone number of the selected contact. I want to retrieve multiple phone numbers if any of the contacts have it and type of phone numbers like work, mobile etc. please help me in this, Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this as this works for me:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
            intent.setType(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_TYPE);
            startActivityForResult(intent, AppConstants.PICK_CONTACT);
```

then in onActivityResult do the following:

```
Cursor cursor = null;
            String phoneNumber = "", primaryMobile = "";

            List<String> allNumbers = new ArrayList<String>();
            int contactIdColumnId = 0, phoneColumnID = 0, nameColumnID = 0;
            try {
                Uri result = data.getData();
                Utils.printLog(TAG, result.toString());
                String id = result.getLastPathSegment();
                cursor = getContentResolver().query(Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, Phone.CONTACT_ID + "=?", new String[] { id }, null);
                contactIdColumnId = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID);
                phoneColumnID = cursor.getColumnIndex(Phone.DATA);
                nameColumnID = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME);

                if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    while (cursor.isAfterLast() == false) {
                        idContactBook = cursor.getString(contactIdColumnId);
                        displayName = cursor.getString(nameColumnID);
                        phoneNumber = cursor.getString(phoneColumnID);

                        if (phoneNumber.length() == 0)
                            continue;

                        int type = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(Phone.TYPE));
                        if (type == Phone.TYPE_MOBILE && primaryMobile.equals(""))
                            primaryMobile = phoneNumber;
                        allNumbers.add(phoneNumber);
                        cursor.moveToNext();
                    }
                } else {
                    // no results actions
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // error actions
            } finally {
                if (cursor != null) {
                    cursor.close();
                }
}
```

Comment: By giving this Phone.TYPE_MOBILE we can get the phonenumbers having type Mobile only is there any method by which i can get all phone number related to one contact. Thanks for your help

Comment: for this you need to add a switch case statement or if else  for example:
switch(type){
case Phone.TYPE_MOBILE:
case Phone.TYPE_WORK:
case Phone.TYPE_HOME:
}

Comment: Can you gve me an example for this?

Comment: i have given you an example in my previus comment try to use it in my code with if else conditions as right now there is only one condition which is of type_mobile you can add an else if statement with other types

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Uri personUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(People.CONTENT_URI, personId);
Uri phonesUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(personUri, People.Phones.CONTENT_DIRECTORY);
String[] proj = new String[] {Phones._ID, Phones.TYPE, Phones.NUMBER, Phones.LABEL}
Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(phonesUri, proj, null, null, null);
```